# dart/flutter - down show doubled list entrys in gridview

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a little problem with the GridView widget. I have loaded every DB entry into a List and now i want to have every type once in the GridView. for example i have 5 entries in the db, all have the same type, then there are 5 widgets on the gridview, but it should be one. also all entries with the same type should be shown on the next page (would be the category_tools_screen and i can show if needed) by clicking on a type widget. the problem here is, that i dont know how to select every type only once and i couldnt find anything really helpfull anywhere. ill show u the related code and.

ill appreciate every comment, thx

categories_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/search.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../model/dummy-data.dart';
import '../widgets/category_item.dart';

class CategoriesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/categoryscreen';
  @override
  _CategoriesScreenState createState() => _CategoriesScreenState();
}

class _CategoriesScreenState extends State<CategoriesScreen> {
  var _isInit = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<Dummy>(context, listen: false).categoryList();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) {});
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      Provider.of<Dummy>(context).categoryList();
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final loadedCategory = Provider.of<Dummy>(
      context,
      listen: false,
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
        title: const Text('Laborkategorien',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, letterSpacing: 1)),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: Search());
              })
        ],
      ),
      body: GridView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
        children: loadedCategory.DUMMY_WERKZEUG
            .map( 
              (catData) => CategoryItem(
                catData.position,
                catData.type,
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
            maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
            childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20,
            mainAxisSpacing: 20),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

category_item.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/model/werkzeug.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../screens/category_tools_screen.dart';
import '../model/dummy-data.dart';
import '../screens/categories_screen.dart';

class CategoryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  CategoryItem(this.id, this.name);
  void selectCategory(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(
      CategoryToolsScreen.routeName,
      arguments: {'bez': id, 'name': name},
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => selectCategory(context),
      splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            name,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
          ),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.red[800].withOpacity(1), 
                Colors.red[800].withOpacity(0.8)
              ],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      ),
    );
    
  }
}
```

dummy_data.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/model/http_excetion.dart';
import 'werkzeug.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Dummy with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Werkzeug> DUMMY_WERKZEUG = [];

  var isLoaded = false;

  Werkzeug findById(String id) {
    return DUMMY_WERKZEUG.firstWhere((prod) => prod.type == id);
  }

  List<Werkzeug> get itemsWerk {
    return [...DUMMY_WERKZEUG];
  }

  Future<void> categoryList() async {
    final url =
        'api';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        'userName': 'snoopy',
        'userPassword': 'schnalle'
      });
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (isLoaded != true) {
        final List<dynamic> extractedData =
            json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
        extractedData.forEach(
            (element) => DUMMY_WERKZEUG.add(Werkzeug.fromJson(element)));
        isLoaded = true;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> toolsList() async {
    final urll =
        'api';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(urll, headers: {
        'userName': 'snoopy',
        'userPassword': 'schnalle',
        'teacherCode': 'sabine'
      });
      if (isLoaded != true) {
        final List<dynamic> extractedData =
            json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
        extractedData.forEach(
            (element) => DUMMY_WERKZEUG.add(Werkzeug.fromJson(element)));
        isLoaded = true;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  final String authToken;
  Dummy(this.authToken, this.DUMMY_WERKZEUG);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Set` and a `List` to solve your case.

For example, lets say you have 10 `Werkzeug` items.

```
List<Werkzeug> mainItems = [/* some data */];
```

Have a `List` and a `Set` like this.

```
List<Werkzeug> finalItems = [];
Set<String> addedTypes = {};
```

Then, loop over your `mainItems` and keep adding Item one by one to your `List` and `Set`. Whenever you add an item, add it's type inside the `Set`. Whenever you add next item, first check if it's type is already present inside the `Set`, if yes, then don't add it.

```
finalItems = mainItems.where((element) {
  if (check.contains(element.type))
    return false; // Means that the type is already in the array so return false to filter out this element
  else {
    // Means type is not present, so add the type to the Set and return true so that element is included in the filter
    check.add(element.type);
    return true;
  }
});
```

Your `finalItems` will contain only the non-duplicates.

Now, inside your build method of `categories_screen.dart`,

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final loadedCategory = Provider.of<Dummy>(
    context,
    listen: false,
  );

  Set<String> addedTypes = {};

  List<Werkzeug> finalItems = loadedCategory.DUMMY_WERKZEUG.where((element) {
    if (addedTypes.contains(element.type))
      return false;
    else {
      addedTypes.add(element.type);
      return true;
    }
  }).toList();

  .... rest of the code
```

Then in your `GridView`,

```
body: GridView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
    children: finalItems
      .map(

  .... rest of the code
```

Comment: The `groupBy` method I've explained is more concise than this, but the final result should be the same.

Comment: firstly thx for the quick answer, but im a little lost atm. Where should i add this? i tried in the dummy_data.dart but it marks the check as false. can u help me further?

Comment: @Marcel Which part is becoming confusing. I can elaborate the answer if you want.

Comment: like i said, i dont know where to paste it in, so did in dummy_data.dart and there it did not know the check

Comment: @Marcel Updated my answer. You should calculate `finalItems` in your build method and then use it in your `GridView` children. Check it out and tell me if you have any other doubt.

Comment: @Nisanth Reddy Yes i saw, thank you, but it still says "Undefined name 'check'" for both. any clue why?

Comment: @Marcel My mistake. Update the answer. It should've been `addedTypes` instead of `check`.

Comment: @Nisanth Reddy it built correctly, but in the app it says "type 'WhereIterable<Werkzeug>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Werkzeug>' See also ...". am i missing sth?

Comment: Yes, my bad again. try adding `.toList()` after `finalItems`. updated my answer

Comment: yes! it works! thank you veeery much my friend! have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupBy` function from [dart:collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) library.

So, you have a list of entries:

```
[
  {'name': 'a', type: 'type_1'},
  {'name': 'b', type: 'type_2'},
  {'name': 'c', type: 'type_1'},
  {'name': 'd', type: 'type_1'},
  {'name': 'e', type: 'type_2'}
]
```

Then you apply the `groupBy` function:

```
groupBy(entries, (obj) => obj.type);
```

As a result, you get a Map of grouped results:

```
{
  'type_1': [
    {'name': 'a', type: 'type_1'},
    {'name': 'c', type: 'type_1'},
    {'name': 'd', type: 'type_1'}
  ],
  'type_2': [
    {'name': 'b', type: 'type_2'},
    {'name': 'e', type: 'type_2'}
  ]
}
```

Now, inside `categories_screen.dart`, provide a single entry for each item in the map (for each type). And for the `category_tools_screen`, pass the items list of the selected category.

Adjust this example based on your data model and you should be good to go.

Comment: This is wonderful. Didn't know about the function in that pacakge.

Comment: But I feel you should also add code that final gives OP the `List` with single elements as well.

Comment: True, but that depends on what info is needed for those "single elements". If only the type is needed to show in the UI, then this should be good enough (you can use the key as a value to provide in the UI).

Comment: That makes sense. Then you can mention the `keys.toList()` may be ?